# Any form to tigger a style by id of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change de color of a burger nav line when pass over an element whit ID or Class, but at this moment nothing works for me.

I found information to change by a clic or when the mouse over the element but not when "cross" the marker with the id:

```
<div class="menu_icon">
    <div class="menu_line menu_line-1"></div>
    <div class="menu_line menu_line-2"></div>
    <div class="menu_line menu_line-3"></div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
   .menu-line{
       background-color: #fff  <-----> to #333
   }
</style>
```

```
<div id="marker">
  "content"
</div>
```

When you get outside the element (with the ID or Class) the values restore to default... is this posible in javascript?

Thanks and see you!

Comment: Did you try CSS `:hover` selector? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_transition_hover.asp

Comment: Is `menu_line` or `menu-line`? They are different.

Comment: You found information for "Click", "Mouse Over", but not "Cross"... what does cross mean?

Comment: Is the first sorry, menu_line.

Comment: I used the expression cross like mean "you are inside the section with ID marker", when you leave this section the default values are restored. It's no literal, that's only an expression

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help.

Simply used [CSS Hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) over burger icon. When user hovers over `.menu_icon`, burger icon turns dark grey. Also possible with JavaScript.

```css
#marker {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.menu_icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: .2s all;
}

.menu_icon:hover {
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="marker">
  <span class="menu_icon">&#9776;</span>
</div>
```